# ajax error in wordpress plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, plugins

I'm writing a plugin for wordpress. The plugin has a widget which contains a button and textbox.
the button has onclick event. 
when that event occurs i need to post the textbox data to php file using ajax
the ajax code doesn't return an error, but php doesn't get the data.

here's my JS file

```
 function F()
    {
        var x=document.getElementById('last').value;


        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/Hovo/Scripts/vote.php',         
            data: x,
            success: function() {
                alert('Sends successfully');
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }
```

here's my php file

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["anun"]))
    {
        echo $_POST['anun'];
    }
    else
    {
        echo "error";
    }
?>
```

please help to fix this problem

Comment: Are you sure about localhost? what you use for server-side at your pc? for example i usq mamp, and my sites on localhost:8888, or on localhost:3000

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP `$_POST` is expecting a key / value pair and you are sending only a value in your ajax. Where '**anun**' would be the key and whatever is stored in `x` is the value.

Since you are not sending the key '**anun**' to `$_POST` it cannot return the value stored in `x` because your `if` condition fails.

You should be able to correct this by changing your ajax call slightly:

```
function F() {

    var x = document.getElementById('last').value;

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/Hovo/Scripts/vote.php',         
        data: { anun: x },
        success: function() {
            alert('Sends successfully');
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

To be sure you are getting the correct value of `x`, try using `console.log(x);` just before your ajax call and check the browser console to see what it returns.

If it does not return the correct value or simply returns nothing, try changing:

```
var x = document.getElementById('last').value;
```

To simply:

```
x = jQuery('#last').val();
```